# How to compare the elements in a vector with another vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have 2 vectors:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [1.5 2.5 3.5];
```

I want to get the following

```
[sum(a(1) < b), sum(a(2) < b), sum(a(3) < b)]

%  3   2   1
```

Is there a way to do this without using `arrayfun` or a  `for` loop?

I am using MATLAB R2014b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to apply an operation to every element in `a` with respect to every element in `b`. The operation is going to be `@lt` (less than). We can then sum down the columns to count how many values in `b` were greater than each value in `a`.

```
sum(bsxfun(@lt, a, b.'), 1)
```

On newer versions of MATLAB (R2016b and newer) you can omit the `bsxfun` and do the following

```
sum(a < b.', 1)
```

Comment: thanks, I should have noticed use sum after using `bsxfun`